# Xamarin Form Slider don't works fine

Tags: visual-studio, slider, xamarin.forms

I have this slider binded

```
<Slider 
  Minimum="0" 
  Maximum="60" 
  Value="{Binding Path=VarName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  Grid.Column="0" 
  Grid.Row="4" 
  Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
  x:Name="sldVarName" 
/>
```

If I tap on the slider the app freezes and I see this data in the VS output windows.

> 03-08 19:45:43.980 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 279, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:43.980 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 287mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:43.980 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 272
>   03-08 19:45:43.985 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 272, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:43.985 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 279mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 273
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 273, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 272mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 265
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 265, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 273mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 258
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 258, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:43.990 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 265mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:43.995 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259
>   03-08 19:45:43.995 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:43.995 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 258mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 273
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 273, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 259mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 273mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:44.000 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 259mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000
>   03-08 19:45:44.005 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259
>   03-08 19:45:44.005 D/ProgressBar(15096): setProgress = 259, fromUser = false
>   03-08 19:45:44.005 D/ProgressBar(15096): mProgress = 259mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 1000

Why the debugger show max = 1000 though I have set to 60? Why does the app freeze?

Comment: Please update your question to include code that generates that log output, relevant code for the object/property you are binding to, and additional relevant xaml code in your page/control that this Slider resides in.

Comment: The problem there is only with Android, with iOS all works fine.
It's very difficulty for me isolate the problem, the project is very big.
There is the possibility to have an extended logs of the error?